# setfsuid() - how to interpret result code?

Tags: linux, libc, setuid, setfsuid

The [man page for `setfsuid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setfsuid.2.html) says:

> On success, the previous value of *fsuid* is returned.  On error, the current value of *fsuid* is returned.

If I'm not wrong one could simply say "***setfsuid() always returns the fsuid value that was set before calling setfsuid() - whether it was successful or not.***"

Is my assumption correct?

If so, and noting that there is *no* `getfsuid()` function, how am I supposed to check if the call succeeded?

As a quick, ugly hack I can only think of calling `setfsuid()` twice and use the return value of the second call...

Comment: Note what it says in the **BUGS** section of that manpage.